# How do I determine if the folder my WPFapplication was started from, is the user startup folder?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to know if my wpf application is started from startup folder or by clicking on desktop link to exe file. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application does not know where it is called from, only where it is executing (working folder).
IMHO your best option is to pass a parameter when launching from a desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

If your installer is adding the shortcut to the startup folder, you could include a command line argument (only for the startup shortcut).  You could then check for this argument.